# Presenting an integer in a non standard money format with PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a `PHP` script that will be used as part of an RPG. The value of money is stored as an integer but needs to be presented slightly differently.

For example if the value is `125050` then it should be shown as `12 gold, 50 silver and 50 copper`. However to complicate matters further sometimes the code will be used for a different system where 10 of each is equal to the next so `125050` would be `1250 gold, 5 silver (and no copper)`. Also some sessions will call for the use of a fourth currency unit (platinum, probably) which will follow the same pattern.

Given that I know that unit divisor is going to be 10 or 100 I need a method of presenting the integer value in the correct format. How can  do this?

I did toy with the idea of casting the int to string and picking of the characters but I would rather use a purely mathematical approach so that I can also separate the int into an array of int like this:

```
// 125050
//  =
$money(
    'copper'=>50,
    'silver'=>50,
    'gold'=>12,
    'platinum'=>0
);
```

UPDATE: After tinkering around with various maths functions I recalled that there was an operator called Modulus. Which I had to look up.[1](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic)

Any way I cooked this little mess up:

```
<?php
// ...
$c = $this->balance % $this->unitSize;
$s = floor($this->balance / $this->unitSize) % $this->unitSize;
$g = floor( ($this->balance / ($this->unitSize *2)) ) % $this->unitSize;
```

I've no idea yet if this is a particularly elegant solution or even a working one.

Comment: What is the value of copper, silver, gold and platinum for both systems? What is the basic unit of measure that you can compare the value against?

Comment: Across all system you have this stored int which represents the value of money held. If we suddenly switched systems the number of gold coins would go up or down but the underlying value remains the same. I need some way to break the numbers out according to the divisor.

Comment: You want `12 gold, 50 silver and 50 copper` , `1250 gold, 5 silver (and no copper)`. Or both (that you should give proper condition). If you want to use 4 digit notation then i suggest to use some formal format like `0050 0050 0012 0000`.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "... where 10 of each is equal..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toyed around with this and got something that should work with whatever denomination system you want to use.

Assuming a denomination array, which maps your denomination values:

```
$denominations = [
        "Hundred Dollar Bill" => 100,
        "Twenty Dollar Bill" => 20,
        "Ten Dollar Bill" => 10,
        "Five Dollar Bill" => 5,
        "One Dollar Bill" => 1,
        "Quarter" => 0.25,
        "Dime" => 0.1,
        "Nickel" => 0.05,
        "Penny" => 0.01
    ];
```

And then a test amount

```
$amount = 312.58;
```

This function will return a comma-delineated breakdown of the amount, based off the denomination array that you pass into it.

```
function breakdownDenominations($amount, $denominations) {
    arsort($denominations); // sort the denomination values from high to low
    $count = array();
    foreach ($denominations as $key=>$value) {
        while ($amount >= $value) {
            $amount = round($amount - $value,2); // decrement by the value of the denomination
            if (!isset($count[$key])) {
                $count[$key] = 1;
            } else {
                $count[$key]++; // track the occurrence of each denomination
            }
        }
    }
    // you could return the $count array here if you want to do database stuff
    $breakdown = array();
    foreach ($count as $key=>$value) {
        $breakdown[] = "$value $key"; // combine the keys with the value for formatting
    }
    return implode (", ",$breakdown); // combine the array into a comma-delineated string
}
```

So running `breakdownDenominations($amount,$denominations)` you get

> 3 Hundred Dollar Bill, 1 Ten Dollar Bill, 2 One Dollar Bill, 2 Quarter, 1 Nickel, 3 Penny

Obviously it doesn't really care about plural state, but you should be able to modify this based off any denomination table.

Comment: Also, you could modify the function to return a simple array of the occurrence count of each denomination. Just return $count after the first foreach loop.

Comment: Hi, I know you wrote this some time ago, however it works a treat! I'm wondering how to get it to also show if numbers are in the negative? I'm using it as a 'copper silver gold' coin, if a balance is in the negative it is just blank, if I add negative denominations the page just loads continuously. Hope you can help?